# Unexpected output while reading string from a keyboard

Tags: c

This program is returning something which I'm not able to comprehend. Attached is the screenshot of the O/P simple program to find number of spaces, tabs, etc.

What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int count[] = { 0, 0, 0 }; /* 0 is spaces, 1 is tabs and 2 for newline. */
    int string;
    
    printf("Enter the paragraph: \n");
    while ((string = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (string == ' ')
            count[0]++;
        else if (string == '\t')
            count[1]++;
        else if (string == '\n')
            count[2]++;
    }
    printf("There are %d Spaces.\n", count[0]);
    printf("There are %d Tabs.\n", count[1]);
    printf("There are %d Newlines.\n", count[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the input, the output, and the expected output? Please add the information as *text* not screenshot.

Comment: The program is working fine for me, what's the problem?

Comment: Signal EOF with `CTRL+D` instead

Comment: `Ctrl+Z` kills the program. you need `Ctrl+D` to end the input.

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` is EOF when running a DOS or Windows console program. Under Linux you use `Ctrl-D`.

Comment: Ctrl D is not working for me. It still prompts for input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot it appears you typed <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> to signal the end of file to your program. While this works in legacy systems such as MS/DOS and the Windows terminals, this key combination has a different meaning on unix systems such as linux: it causes the current process to be suspended by its the running shell parent. The process can be resumed later with the `fg` command.

To signal the end on file on this system, you should type <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> instead.

Your program should produce the expected result then. The code seems OK, albeit it is quite confusing to name `string` an `int` variable that gets a single byte from `getchar()`. Such a variable is usually named `c`.

Comment: I changed the condition to '$' to exit the input and it worked. Ctrl D was not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send an `EOF` in order to stop reading you should use `CTRL+D`.

Comment: Linux: Ctrl-D. Windows: Ctrl-Z.